TypeScript Error: Parameter 'element' implicitly has an 'any' type in forEach loop even after defining type
I'm working on a TypeScript project in Visual Studio Code and I'm encountering an issue with the type of a parameter in a forEach loop. Here's the relevant code snippet from my search-car.component.ts file:
searchCar() {
  console.log(this.validateForm.value);
  this.isSpinning = true;
  this.adminService.searchCar(this.validateForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
    res.carDtoList.forEach((element: any) => {
      element.processedImg = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + element.returnedImg;
      this.cars.push(element);
    });
    console.log(res)
    this.isSpinning = false;
  })
}

it returns
X [ERROR] TS7006: Parameter 'element' implicitly has an 'any' type. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/modules/customer/components/search-car/search-car.component.ts:38:29:
      38 │       res.carDtoList.forEach(element => {
    
Screenshot
[![angular][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/r7sIx.png


You need to create an interface for Car which contains all the properties of the object.
export interface Car {
    name: string;
    ...
}

Then use this interface and set the type of element to Car this will resolve your issue!
...
cars: Array<Car> = [];

searchCar() {
  console.log(this.validateForm.value);
  this.isSpinning = true;
  this.adminService.searchCar(this.validateForm.value).subscribe((res: { carDtoList: Array<Car> }) => {
    res.carDtoList.forEach((element: Car) => { // <- changed here!
      element.processedImg = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + element.returnedImg;
      this.cars.push(element);
    });
    console.log(res)
    this.isSpinning = false;
  })
}


An alternative would be just to define any type to the element
...
res.carDtoList.forEach((element: any) => {
...


@Naran Murali if i try res.carDtoList.forEach(element: any) => {
i get this error  src/app/modules/customer/components/search-car/search-car.component.ts:38:29:
38 │       res.carDtoList.forEach(element => {
╵                              ~~~~~~~

@Max sorry typo from my side, check now!

still returns
X [ERROR] TS7006: Parameter 'element' implicitly has an 'any' type. [plugin angular-compiler]
src/app/modules/customer/components/search-car/search-car.component.ts:38:29:
  38 │       res.carDtoList.forEach(element => {
     ╵                              ~~~~~~~


sure can do that

@Max updated my answer! ensure you have the type properties setup properly for Car, they should be all the properties that are present inside that object!

@Max if that does not work, just replace the type Car with any in the code modified, might fix your issue! but try this as last resort!
